# Squeaky subfloor

Tags: flooring, subfloor, squeak

Does anyone have any other tips and tricks to stop subfloor under carpet on second floor from sqeaking? There is no access to joists from below due to drywall ceiling.
I've seen some special construction screw method where you drill the screw into the floor (until you find a joist) and with the tool they snap the head off clean.

[image: example]

Comment: Are you removing your carpet or not?

Comment: No. I am not removing the carpet.

Comment: No head what would keep the sub floor from moving? If you don't like squeaks get some ear plugs or add a screws that clamp or pull the subfloor tight to the joices, can't. Pull carpet up and do this then replace the carpet or put it back down well or? , get used to the noise , this is my opinion but a headless screw sounds about as good as a nail with the head cut off.

Comment: @EdBeal - These screws are a specially designed with a larger pitch thread at the starting end and then a smaller pitch up to the break off point. The idea is that the upper thread will stay in the flooring and the larger pitch in the joist will advance that part of the screw faster and draw the flooring down to the joist. Even if the flooring does not fully draw down to the joist the upper thread is supposed to stay engaged in the flooring and bridge the gap. Installing these must be done with the spacer jig that prevents driving the screw deeper than the break off score mark.

Comment: I purchased a whole kit of these to address some squeaks in my house but have yet to try them out so cannot vouch for how effective they may be.

Comment: Ok I see standard screws and a screw with a "head" that is snapped off from the description. This is why I left as a comment, I shim , glue and screw but have not seen these.

Comment: I think you're referring to https://www.squeakyfloor.com/counter-snap/.  I've seen this from a This Old House segment (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gUW-IhSMBc).

Comment: I think i may try this squeaky floor product and see how it goes. Doesn't seem like I have an option especially with the carpet remaining. Finding the joists will be the biggest pain.

Comment: I have used these successfully...1 more room to go, new squeaks. No return squeaks in 5 years where I have used them.

Comment: Apparently finding the joist is not that bad. Those special long smooth shank screws are supposed to be used to locate the joist by screwing repeatedly in the flooring until you hit a joist. From there you measure over to find the next joist around the squeak area.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the info everyone. I'll buy some and try it out.